# OneToOne mapping with unique child table relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to link a table A with a table B with a OneToOne relation, the table B holds a foreign key on one column from table A. The problem is that the table B actually holds a one to many relation, because of storing old data. Only one instance of A is present in table B with B.dt_update null. In short I have a one to many, but restricted to 1 to zero or 1 through a restriction.

How should I design this using JPA annotations?

roughly I have (not working of course since it is not a one to one situation as such)

```
@Entity
class A{
....
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    B b;
...
}
```

--

```
@Entity
class B{
...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private A a;

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-121), onetoOne is a little tricky, it is better to go with the Many to One with unique = true.

```
@Entity
class A{
....
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name ="id")
    B b;
...
}

@Entity
class B{
...
    @ManyToOne    
    @JoinColumn(name ="id",unique="true")
    private A a;

...
}
```

Comment: But sorry for my ignorance but how would this know which restriction I want? I have a field in B (dt_end) that should be null, for all older revisions this will have a date set.